# Bookmark keyword for "I'm Feeling Lucky"

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, keyword, feeling-lucky

I want to add a [bookmark keyword](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html) in Firefox for Google's `I'm Feeling Lucky` but the URL changes too quickly for me to copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in [@Andy Mikula's answer](https://superuser.com/a/3101/1682) no longer works since Google takes you to a 'redirect confirmation' page—thus beating the purpose of using the bookmarklet.

The alternative is to change the **default search engine** in your browser to **DuckDuckGo.com**. Then use the '**!**' (exclamation mark) followed by `space` and your search term. If you need to use regular Google, you will need to visit the site and search there.

Answer (score 4):

It's `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky` (from the bottom of your [link](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html)), where '%s' is the search string.

Comment: *chortle* This amuses me.

Comment: You only need `&btnI=&`.

Comment: This shows just a forwarding note from google

Answer (score 1):

This link for example searches for "French Military Victories"

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=french+military+victories&btnI=745

Comment: +1 for providing the short version ("btnI=745"). But I think it is a bad example as the result is empty (it's an old joke (by Scott Hanselman?)) and does not really demonstrate that it works. If "CPU" is used instead of "french military victories" then it will open the top result (a Wikipedia article in this example).

Comment: i also get here a forwarding note

Answer (score 1):

If you just type your search terms into the address bar in Firefox, it will perform an 'I'm feeling lucky' search by default.
You may have issues with your ISP redirecting you to a lame 'domain not found' page, though.  This is because Firefox attempts to look up the site first and only performs the search once the lookup fails.  My ISP allowed me to opt out of it, so it's not a big issue.

Answer (score -1):

[@LWTBP noted](https://superuser.com/a/1679981) that [@Andy Mikula's answer](https://superuser.com/a/3101)  "no longer works since Google takes you to a 'redirect confirmation' page."

A few potential workarounds:

- `https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=%s`: an [answer to a similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/111050) on `webapps.stackexchange.com` suggests this URL, which works for me when combined with the [Redirect Google Redirects](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-google-redirects/nlacgjiklmjjejlgoclnjhndjaiempdo) chrome extension. I've also had success using that extension in combination with @Andy Mikula's answer.
- `https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1`: as of 2023-05, this url works for me *sometimes*. In my experiments, this URL skipped the redirect page when used with Google Chrome but not with Firefox. Also, the "I'm feeling lucky" feature kicks in only sometimes. Other times, it seems to give a normal google search page. For example, searching for `github pyright` with this url might give a google search page, whereas `site:github.com pyright` successfully redirects to https://github.com/microsoft/pyright. The URL suggested above comes from a review that I read on the reviews page of the [Redirect Google Redirects](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-google-redirects/nlacgjiklmjjejlgoclnjhndjaiempdo) chrome extension.

In each of the above sugggested URLs, `%s` is the search string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just tested it, didn't work for me.